# Material-UI - Is there a way to allow right click to close Modal?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to be able to close a `Menu` (or to be more specific, a `Popover`) with a right click, any `mousedown` event to be clear.

I've found this on the documentation: https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#MenuListComposition.js

Which I have then cleaned a bit. Here is what I've got: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-react-8nqqb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

If you check it you can see that the `Popper` closes on right click, but now I can scroll the page while the menu is open :/

This is almost what I need but I was not able to do the same with a `Popover` since it uses `Modal` internally and it seems either they don't use the `ClickAwayListener` or they don't expose a way to modify its props.

So if anyone knows how to make `mousedown` events close a `Popover` or prevent scrolling when a `Popper` is open I'll be more than happy to hear any solution.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571947/12775991) I got a direction, I tweaked the given sandbox and I managed to do what I wanted. I finally had to use the `Popper` and prevent scroll when it's open.

Here's the final sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-ui-react-1qroy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to disable scrolling if the popper is open.

```
    window.onscroll = open ? null : () => window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-react-zysue

Here's the same example with popover instead of popper

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-react-n0bf9